# How can I use a map function in SML to implement this code?

Tags: recursion, sml, map-function

```
fun add nil = nil    
 | add ((a ,b) :: c) = (a+b) :: (add c);
```

I've just started learning SML, and the map function is new to me.

How can I use a map function in SML to implement this code?

Comment: `val add = map op+`

Answer (score 2):

```
-val a = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)];
val a = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)] : (int * int) list
- map (fn (x, y) => x + y) a;
val it = [3,5,7] : int list
```